# Prevent overlap with fixed form at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am building a messaging page which has a typical form which is **fixed** at the bottom of the page.

The messages are dynamically generated and placed in `<li>` tags.

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="messages" style="overflow:auto;">
   <!-- Messages are dynamically added as <li> here -->
</ul>

<form  action="">
       <input id="m" autocomplete="off"/>
       <button type="submit" name="action">Send</button> 
</form>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
form {padding: 20px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 80%; }
form input {color: black; border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
#messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
#messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
```

What happens is that the messages which are dynamically added overflow on top of the form which is fixed at the bottom.

I want to only allow the messages to appear until the form, and then become scroll-able.

Here is the current scenario: [image: a busy cat]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form has transparent background by default. In this case you can do something simple:

```
form {
  padding: 20px; 
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  background: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f3ukjyce/

However, there are better ways of structuring this. The problem is that you'll always have a couple messages hidden behind the form. You need to rework this so that the scrolled content is contained within it's own element and doesn't overlap the form.

https://jsfiddle.net/f3ukjyce/1/

Comment: I like your idea! Appreciate the simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox layout, I added a `<div id="container">` around the `<ul>` and `<form>`.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#messages {
  overflow: auto;
}
form {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxe2775t/)**

If you want the messages to grow from bottom to top, you can add a `:before` pseudo element.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#container:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
}
#messages {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3957v30q/)**

Comment: Thanks for an elaborate answer! Very interesting that you used 'vh' as the unit for height. This is the first time that I'm coming across it!

Comment: @Arjun It's always exciting to know learn something new, no offensive, how does the answer you accepted solve the issues!? messages go behind the form in 1st demo, messed up scrolls in 2nd demo.